# After giving content root path to python from spark im getting this error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

```
C:\Users\nande\PycharmProjects\Big_Data_Project_USA_Pharma\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\nande\PycharmProjects\Big_Data_Project_USA_Pharma\driver.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nande\PycharmProjects\Big_Data_Project_USA_Pharma\driver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from create_spark import get_spark_object
  File "C:\Users\nande\PycharmProjects\Big_Data_Project_USA_Pharma\create_spark.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pyspark import cloudpickle
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: code expected at least 16 arguments, got 15

Process finished with exit code 1
```

java  version: 1.8.0_251
python version: Python 3.11.5
pyspark in Pycharm: 3.4.1

While doing the project set-up I have given access to the content root as C:/spark/python
after giving this content root I started getting this issue
How do we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After Downgrading to spark 3.3.1 issue got resolved.